# Configuration of dummy default vhost and prevent virtual host fallback with https requests to IP-PD host

Tags: ssl, https, sni, http-status-code

### Background

Consider 4 hypothetical FQDNs that all resolve to 192.0.2.42:

- example.com
- [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)
- foo.example.org
- legacy.example.net

Now, consider two hypothetical servers bound to 192.0.2.42 (obviously, not at the same time... I'm just illustrating two different scenarios):

- Server has one "site" that's the default. Any https request directed to port 443 of a FQDN that resolves to the server's IP address ends up mapping to it.
- Server has name-based virtual hosts enabled. The vhost to which example.com and [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) is the catch-all default. foo.example.org and legacy.example.net are mapped to two other vhosts.

### The Problem:

Requests to https://example.com, https://www.example.com, https://foo.example.org, and https://legacy.example.net all work as expected... but two undesired side effects exist as well:

- https://192.0.2.42 (what RFC-9110 calls an "[IP-PD reference identity](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110.html#name-ip-id-reference-identity)") falls through to the default site after the browser displays a warning & the user swats it away. Strict-Transport-Security headers won't save the day.
- An attacker can point a domain under his control (say, "badguys.example") to 192.0.2.42, send the user to https://badguys.example, and (assuming the actual FQDN is a bit less blatantly bad, the browser itself is buggy, and/or the user is a complete idiot), and the same scenario as 192.0.2.42 comes into play. Once again, STS won't save the day.

### The Solution (the devil's in the details)

From what I understand, the proper solution is something along the following lines:

- Enable name-based virtual hosts, if not already done.
- Create a "dummy-default" vhost that catches all requests that aren't explicitly mapped to one of the "real" vhosts.
- Configure SNI. Among other things, the default vhost is responsible for presenting a TLS cert with example.com, [www.example.com](http://www.example.com), foo.example.org, and legacy.example.net in the SAN

### The gory details?

- The default vhost needs a unique FQDN of its own that resolves to 192.0.2.42 (as opposed to 127.0.0.1, or some other IP address... otherwise, SNI will fail.) Right?
- It doesn't have to be GLOBALLY DNS-resolvable... it's good enough to just stuff it into /etc/hosts on the server running Apache (or Nginx, or Tomcat, or whatever the server is running). Right?
- The default vhost's FQDN (say, "default999.example.com") needs to be in the SAN, along with the other 4 names. Otherwise, when Apache (or whatever) goes to start up, it'll sanity-check the cert for its default host & crap out if everything isn't 100% perfect. Right?
- It de-facto has to be a subdomain of a TLD under the organization's control (like "default999.example.com"), because no CA will allow you to stick an IP address or a hostname that isn't both theoretically DNS-resolvable AND under a TLD you demonstrably own & control) into the SAN. Right?
- Assuming the desired behavior for the default vhost is, "handle all requests by returning a 4xx status code"... which one is, in fact, the most appropriate?

  - 421?
  - 422?
  - 400?

Before I went to really scrutinize the list of 4xx response codes, I thought *for sure* there would be at least one that specifically relates to vhosts and explicitly means something like, "You made a http(s) request to a URL whose FQDN resolves to the IP address of this server, but this server has not mapped it to a site and is therefore returning this error."

Except... as far as I can tell, over the span of approximately 25+ years since Apache first introduced name-based virtual hosts, nobody involved with IETF (or Microsoft, Apache, or anyone else) has apparently ever thought errors specific to them were important enough to merit a proper http response code of its own. 421 or 422 *almost* seem to match... but after reading their official definitions [(RFC 9110)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110.html#name-421-misdirected-request), I'm not so sure.

- It sounds like [421](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110.html#name-421-misdirected-request) only applies to http2 requests in scenarios where the user agent combines requests for two vhosts on the same server that the server itself refuses to allow to be combined.
- It sounds like [422](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110.html#name-422-unprocessable-content) is only supposed to be used in scenarios where you're encoding a request to the server as xml in the body of a request
- I've seen a few posts here suggesting 404... but to me, 404 has *always* meant, "good site, bad file". Maybe I'm being pedantic, but it just feels viscerally wrong & inappropriate to return 404 when the host *itself* is invalid.

So... does **400 (Invalid Host)** sound like the best choice, or can someone think of a better one?

Finally... getting back to the **most important** part of the question... am I correct about having to give the default vhost a real fqdn that's listed in the SAN? At least, with Apache, Nginx, and IIS?